# How to pass variables from backing bean in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am unable to pass and then retrieve variable from a backing bean. My add() function is called when a tree node is selected:

```
public void add(TreeNode selectedTreeNode) {
    setMyid(((MyClass) selectedTreeNode.getData()).getId());

    System.out.println("id : " + getMyid());

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlgVar').show()");
}
```

---

```
public String saveAction() {
    String myid = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
        getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("myid");
    System.out.println("myid : " + myid);
}

public void setMyid(String myid) {
   this.myid = myid;
}

public String getMyid() {
   return myid;
}
```

The dialog is:

```
<p:dialog id="dlgId" widgetVar="dlgVar" dynamic="true">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1"> 
            <h:outputLabel for="nametext" value="Name" />
           <p:inputText id="nametext" value="#{myBean.name}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{myBean.saveAction}" >
           <f:param name="myid" value="#{myBean.myid}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

The id printed in saveAction() is null but it is not null when set in add().

How can I set myid from backing bean so that it is correctly passed back to saveAction()?

Comment: and How do you get it ?!? (add your get id method )

Comment: The set and get methods are already listed above. In my saveAction() I use getRequestParameterMap() to retrieve myid.

Comment: what i am not understanding is why using param if you are not moving to another page even if you are in the same ManagedBean and why using a STring method in your actionListner

Comment: My page is split into 2 panes- the left pane has treenode menus and the right pane display the outcome of the current selected node. The right pane will also has some command buttons. If right mouse button is clicked on the treenode in the left pane and one of the menus selected or command button is clicked in the right pane then a dialog will be displayed. The dialog xhtml is in the same page but the managed bean may or may not be the same. Variables from the Treenode backing bean code are not available in the dialog backing bean so I need to pass these to dialog. How can I do this?

Comment: Apparently you have two different backing beans and needs to pass the value of a variable in your treenodeBean to a variable in dialogBean, correct? Your add() function is in treenodeBean and saveAction() is in dialogBean?